# Vertically align elements to the bottom of div columns

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I've created a Wordpress theme for a client, and managed to allow them to create columns on their page. However, the columns differ slightly in height, making buttons look weird. You can see for yourself [here](http://www.assists.be/diensten/). The site is in Dutch, but the read-more-buttons are clearly not aligned with each other.

I've created [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/petermorlion/5jbhzs2f/1/) where I've managed to make the columns the same height, but I can't manage to align the links to the bottom of the div. I've tried `display: table-cell`, `table-row`, etc.

```css
.column-main {
  display: table-row;
}

.column-page-column {
  width: 32%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.column-page-column p.call-to-action {
  // thought this might, work but it doesn't
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

article {border: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<div class="column-main hentry-wrapper column-main-3">
  
  <article class="column-page-column">
   <div class="hentry-wrapper">
    <header class="entry-header">
     <h3 class="entry-title">Title 1</h3>
      </header>
    <div class="entry-content">
     <p>Blah blah blah</p>
        <p class="call-to-action"><a class="button" href="#">Read more</a></p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  
  <article class="column-page-column">
   <div class="hentry-wrapper">
    <header class="entry-header">
     <h3 class="entry-title">Title 2</h3>
      </header>
    <div class="entry-content">
     <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eleifend rhoncus malesuada. Donec a risus nec nunc dignissim egestas eget ac erat. Nullam elementum sagittis sollicitudin. 
        </p>
        <p class="call-to-action"><a class="button" href="#">Read more</a></p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  
  <article class="column-page-column">
   <div class="hentry-wrapper">
    <header class="entry-header">
     <h3 class="entry-title">Title 2</h3>
      </header>
    <div class="entry-content">
     <p>
          Blah blah blah, more bla bla, lorem ipsum and stuff. Buzz words,
          and so on, etc etc etc.
        </p>
        <p class="call-to-action"><a class="button" href="#">Read more</a></p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </article>

  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to move the links down so they align with each other? I control the Wordpress theme, so I can alter the html, if necessary.

Comment: Two Options.
1) Use table tags and arrange the contents in cells. Make sure that the `call-to-action` and `entry-content` are in different rows.
2) Use javascript or jQuery. After the page loads, determine the heights of `entry-content` and find the max height. Then set all of the others to that height.

Comment: here is a variant: https://jsfiddle.net/dmkoeam8/

Comment: @bobjoe Luckily in 2016 (almost 2017) there are many more options besides "use tables" and "use JS" when it comes to CSS layout issues.

Comment: Were any of the solutions useful?

Comment: @Peter Have you tested any of these three answers below?

Comment: Yes, sorry, thought I had already marked an answer. I went with @SohrabHejazi's answer, more or less, because it was easier in my case. But I think using Flexbox is the better, more modern answer, which I'd recommend to other users. I will most likely be changing my implementation in the future.

Comment: @Peter Awesome. I'll give his answer an upvote then!

Comment: @Peter - Glad it worked out.  Flexbox is definitely a more modern and desirable solution.  However, it is not compatible with some of the older browsers.  Something to keep in mind depending on your target audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using one implementation of flexbox, and greatly reducing the number of container elements you have around your content, you can achieve this:

```css
.column-main {
    display: flex;
}
.column-page-column {
    width: 33%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.column-page-column p {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-main">
    <article class="column-page-column">
        <h3 class="entry-title">Title 1</h3>
        <p>Blah blah blah</p>
        <a class="button" href="#">Read more</a>
    </article>
    <article class="column-page-column">
        <h3 class="entry-title">Title 2</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eleifend rhoncus malesuada. Donec a risus nec nunc dignissim egestas eget ac erat. Nullam elementum sagittis sollicitudin.</p>
        <a class="button" href="#">Read more</a>
    </article>
    <article class="column-page-column">
        <h3 class="entry-title">Title 2</h3>
        <p>Blah blah blah, more bla bla, lorem ipsum and stuff. Buzz words, and so on, etc etc etc.</p>
        <a class="button" href="#">Read more</a>
    </article>
</div>
```

The key is `flex-grow: 1`, which tells the `<p>` elements to take up all the remaining space in the container.

Answer (score 2):

I had to restructure your code a bit.
Besides from this method, Using Flexbox is another good option.

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c97Lz4ab/)

```css
.column-main {
  display: table-row;
}

.column-page-column {
  width: 32%;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.column-page-column p.call-to-action {
  // thought this might, work but it doesn't
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

div.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  
}

article {border: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<div class="column-main hentry-wrapper column-main-3">
  
  <article class="column-page-column">
   <div class="hentry-wrapper">
    <header class="entry-header">
     <h3 class="entry-title">Title 1</h3>
      </header>
    <div class="entry-content">
     <p>Blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <p class="call-to-action"><a class="button" href="#">Read more</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  
  <article class="column-page-column">
   <div class="hentry-wrapper">
    <header class="entry-header">
     <h3 class="entry-title">Title 2</h3>
      </header>
    <div class="entry-content">
     <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eleifend rhoncus malesuada. Donec a risus nec nunc dignissim egestas eget ac erat. Nullam elementum sagittis sollicitudin. 
        </p>
    </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <p class="call-to-action"><a class="button" href="#">Read more</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  
  <article class="column-page-column">
   <div class="hentry-wrapper">
    <header class="entry-header">
     <h3 class="entry-title">Title 2</h3>
      </header>
    <div class="entry-content">
     <p>
          Blah blah blah, more bla bla, lorem ipsum and stuff. Buzz words,
          and so on, etc etc etc.
        </p>
    </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <p class="call-to-action"><a class="button" href="#">Read more</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>

  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an artificial padding to the bottom of the posts.  Say like `padding-bottom: 3em;` Then make the `position:relative` on the post and the `position:absolute;` on the link.  Set the `bottom:0` or `.5em` and that should always place that link at the bottom of the containers. You could also try using Foundation's plugin "Equalizer" http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/equalizer.html That should give you the correct illusion.